# Utilizar datos de una lista interna de Conjunto de datos en informe RDCL para realizar Grafico

Tags: c#, wpf, gráficas, rdlc

Mi situacion es la siguiente:

Estoy programando en WPF - C#, y usando reportes RDLC.

**Tengo un reporte que básicamente me muestra el conjunto de artículos del stock que un cliente tiene en "Acopio" (artículos adquiridos pero sin retirar), los cuales a su vez fueron adquiridos en diferentes momentos por medio de diferentes comprobantes**.

Para ello utilizo la siguiente clase

```
class DisplayArticulo 
{
 
        public Int32 ID_Articulo { get; set; }
.
.
.
.
 public  List<ComprobanteConAcopio> comprobantesAcopio = new List<ComprobanteConAcopio>();

}
```

donde ComprobanteConAcopio es una clase en la que guardo datos como la fecha del comprobante del cual quedan articulos en acopio, la cantidad del mismo que queda en acopio, etc.

El informe RDLC esta estructurado con una lista, y dentro de la misma un Rectángulo con datos del articulo como código, descripción, cantidad del mismo en acopio, etc.

Esa lista que muestra cada uno de los artículos en acopio tiene como DataSet un conjunto de datos llamado "DatosArticulos", el cual es cargado de manera previa con una

```
List<DisplayArticulo> listaArticulos= new List<DisplayArticulo>()
```

**Cada objeto de la lista es un articulo del cual el cliente tiene acopio y dentro de cada articulo hay una lista con los datos de cada comprobante que tiene articulos de ese id sin retirar**.

Hasta ahi todo perfecto.

El problema reside en que **para cada articulo, dentro del mismo rectangulo de la tabla, quiero incluir un grafico del tipo temporal, el cual en el eje de X me muestre las fechas y en el eje de las Y me muestre la cantidad de unidades del articulo en acopio que se adquirio cada vez** (espero ser claro en este punto de la explicacion).

Es alli donde se me complica, porque como se imaginaran, **mi idea original es utilizar los datos de los comprobantes con existencias (la fecha y la cantidad) de cada articulo que en un primer momento guarde en la lista**

```
comprobantesAcopio
```

**dentro de cada instancia** de DisplayArticulo de la lista

```
listaArticulos
```

Como se imaginaran, el conjunto de datos ni siquiera me muestra la lista "comprobantesAcopio" de la clase DisplayArticulo, por lo que **no puedo acceder a esos datos multiples (multiples comprobantes) de cada articulo.**

Alguien puede darme una idea para llegar a hacer esto?

Desde ya muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Para mostrar un gráfico temporal en un informe RDLC en WPF-C# que represente las adquisiciones de artículos en acopio a lo largo del tiempo, puedes seguir estos pasos:

1. Preparar los datos:

Asegúrate de tener los datos necesarios en una estructura que se pueda enlazar al informe RDLC. En tu caso, tienes una lista de objetos DisplayArticulo, cada uno con su propia lista de ComprobanteConAcopio. Para simplificar el proceso, puedes crear una nueva clase que represente los datos del gráfico temporal. Por ejemplo:

```
class ArticuloAdquisicion
{
    public string CodigoArticulo { get; set; }
    public DateTime Fecha { get; set; }
    public int CantidadAdquirida { get; set; }
}
```

2. Procesar los datos:

A partir de tus listas existentes, puedes crear una nueva lista de ArticuloAdquisicion que contenga los datos necesarios para el gráfico. Recorre tus listas originales y agrega las entradas correspondientes a la nueva lista.

```
List<ArticuloAdquisicion> datosGrafico = new List<ArticuloAdquisicion>();

foreach (var articulo in listaArticulos)
{
    foreach (var comprobante in articulo.comprobantesAcopio)
    {
        datosGrafico.Add(new ArticuloAdquisicion
        {
            CodigoArticulo = articulo.Codigo, // Asegúrate de tener una propiedad que almacene el código del artículo
            Fecha = comprobante.Fecha,
            CantidadAdquirida = comprobante.Cantidad // Ajusta esto según la propiedad real en tu clase ComprobanteConAcopio
        });
    }
}
```

3. Enlazar el informe RDLC:
   En el informe RDLC, crea un gráfico y enlázalo al conjunto de datos "DatosArticulos". Asegúrate de configurar las series correctamente. En tu caso, la serie de tiempo debería utilizar la fecha en el eje X y la cantidad en el eje Y. Puedes agrupar los datos por el código del artículo si deseas mostrar múltiples gráficos, uno por artículo.
4. Mostrar el informe:
   Finalmente, en tu aplicación WPF, carga el informe RDLC y enlázalo a la lista de **ArticuloAdquisicion** que creaste anteriormente. Asegúrate de configurar los parámetros y visibilidad del gráfico en el informe según tus requisitos.

Este enfoque debería permitirte mostrar un gráfico temporal en tu informe RDLC que representa las adquisiciones de artículos en acopio a lo largo del tiempo para cada artículo. Asegúrate de ajustar los nombres de las propiedades y los detalles de la configuración del gráfico según tu implementación específica.

Comment: Hola Santiago, muchas gracias por tomarte un tiempo para responder! esta muy bueno y claro tu aporte, el cual voy a poner en practica. Es otra manera de ver e;l problema en la cual no habia pensado. Gracias de nuevo!.